# Jquery make array with divs

Tags: jquery

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="location_container">
    <div id='option_div_138'>test1</div>
    <div id='option_div_139'>test2</div>
    <div id='option_div_140'>test3</div>
</div>
```

When i alert this datastring:

```
var dataString = "";
alert (dataString); return false;
```

I want to see:

```
location_container=%5B%5D=option_div_138&location_container=%5B%5D=option_div_139&location_container=%5B%5D=option_div_140
```

or better:

```
location_container=%5B%5D=138&location_container=%5B%5D=139&location_container=%5B%5D=140
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: does $("location_container").serialize() work?

Comment: Yes, but it not gives the desired result. I must also get the existing results to save.

Answer (score 0):

without any code in your example - here's all i can assist with:

```
var yourArrayOfDivElements = $("#location_container div"); 
for (var i=0; i< yourArrayOfDivElements.length; i++)
 {
   alert(yourArrayOfDivElements[i].id);
  }
```

this wont produce the explicit results you are looking for, but it will illustrate the list that the first line produces. Good luck!

edit : here's a jsFiddle example to illustrate use of the above - http://jsfiddle.net/WSQvS/

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your help.

This have I already try, but then i get a datastring like option_div_138,option_div_139,option_div_140 and this can't I save in my php script

Comment: var count = $.map($("#location_container div[id]"), function(n, i) {
 return n.id;
});

var dataString = "location_container=" + count;

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "/bin/jobchange.process.php",
 data: dataString
});

This I have had.

Answer (score 0):

This works. But the id's are hardcoded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mystring = "";
$("#location_container").children("div[id^=option_div_]").each(function(){
    mystring += "location_container=[]="+$(this).attr("id").replace("option_div_","")+"&";
});
mystring = mystring.substring(0,mystring.length-1);
alert(mystring);
</script>
```